# What does the output of traceroute mean?

Tags: traceroute

I entered **traceroute bbc.co.uk** and a lot of information came up, what is the purpose and meaning of this information?

Comment: Hi Tom Scott, thanks for posting in the SU community. Please take some time to be familiar with it by taking the quick tour : http://superuser.com/tour You'll then be able to understand what is a good question and what is not.

Comment: Also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traceroute shows each hop that a packet has to go through from your host to the destination host (in this case **bbc.co.uk**).

Each one of these steps is represented in a line. The first column is the hop number. The next three columns show the amount of time to get to that hop. (traceroute sends 3 packets and measures the answer from each one of them).

Finally the IP address and if it's possible the DNS name of the hop.

Using traceroute you can debug a failing connection, discover how far away is a server from you or verify if a site is down or if it's your connection.

If the device or server in the hop is unable to answer the traceroute packets then you'll see stars in the row as a way to show you a timeout in the response.

Comment: Also, there are 30 lines and only the first line has information in it. In the other 29 lines there are simply 3 stars, what does this mean?

Comment: @TomScott Probably a firewall is blocking your ICMP packets

Comment: @TomScott These lines are hops that the packet goes through, but for some reason (like a firewall) you can't ping it to find out what it is.

Answer (score 3):

From traceroute manual:

> traceroute - print the route packets trace to network host
>
> traceroute tracks the route packets taken from an IP network on their
>   way to a given host. It utilizes the IP protocol's time to live (TTL)
>   field and attempts to elicit an ICMP TIME_EXCEEDED response from each
>   gateway along the path to the host.

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering, why do I always get so many dislikes, what is wrong with the question?

Comment: You have asked without reading the traceroute manual before. That should be your first step before asking. The second step should be ask to Google :)

Comment: Ok. I'll consider this in future, thank you.